# Navbar row not vertically aligned

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, navbar

I am trying to make a navbar which hides text on smaller screens.  I cannot get the bar to align correctly!

http://jsfiddle.net/blisstdev/ZrA3u/10/

http://jsfiddle.net/blisstdev/ZrA3u/10/embedded/result/

As you can see, the left side is lower than the right!

Also, the first list element of the 'ul' on the left does not fill the size of the 'ul' container, yet all the other list elements do.  Why is this?

Thank you very much!

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top header" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid header-top">
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-left pull-left list-inline contact-links">
          <li class="header-link-container"><a class="visible-xs call-link" href="tel:180042762687"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></a><span class="hidden-xs header-link-text">1-800-GARMANTS</span></li>

          <li class="header-link-container"><a class="to-do magento-add-in chat-link" href='****live chat**'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span><span class="hidden-xs header-link-text">Chat</span></a></li>
          <li class="header-link-container"><a class="magento-add-in email-link" href="mailto:ryan@garmants.com"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span><span class="hidden-xs header-link-text">Email</span></a></li>
          </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right pull-right list-inline account-and-cart-links">
        <li class="header-link-container"><a class="account-link" href="my-account.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><span class="hidden-xs header-link-text">My Account</span></a></li>
        <li class="header-link-container"><a class="cart-link" href="my-cart.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span><span class="hidden-xs header-link-text">My Cart</span></a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Correctly" doesn't have a meaning on its own. It has to be defined in relation to an expected result. :-)

Comment: Silly silly.  Let's say aligning correctly = 'tops of all visual objects in the navbar intersecting on a common horizontal line'.  Can you help me with that? :-)

Comment: I noticed a CSS tag there for your question, but where is your stylesheet? Usually conflicting styles are the cause of this. Perhaps you can put CSS in your jsfiddle or edit your post and add it there? It would really help me identify the problem.

Comment: thanks Brendan.  I'm using the Bootstrap stylesheet only.  http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css  .  It's in the "External Resources of the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On small screens, the anchors are set to `display: block`, while this is not the case for the anchors in the right hand list. Just make sure to apply the same styles to each list and they will behave in the same way.

Comment: YES.  That was definitely it!  However there's still one last problem.  I still have the first list element on the left not filling the whole block on screens larger than mobile, thus making the text appear out of alignment.  See http://jsfiddle.net/blisstdev/ZrA3u/10/embedded/result/   Thank you!

Comment: There's a strange rule in line 7 of your boostrap.css of `display: none !important` that's getting in the way: `.visible-xs, .visible-sm, .visible-md, .visible-lg {display: none!important;}` You'll have to remove or override that somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I updated you [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrA3u/11/) you need to set the same padding to the first `<li>` item in the left nav-bar like this

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .contact-links.navbar-nav > li.header-link-container:nth-child(1) {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
}
```

should do it.

Comment: Thanks!  However, this answer isn't quite satisfying because I still don't understand why that link isn't aligned with the rest of the links already!  I've updated the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/blisstdev/ZrA3u/13/  http://jsfiddle.net/blisstdev/ZrA3u/13/embedded/result/